# Assembly Language Errors

Tags: assembly, undefined

If I could get some comments on how this should be done I think I'm on the right path but am not sure how much of it is correct. I hope all the code I provide will help and also here are the instructions on what the program needs to do. Write in assembly language  (in  a  separate file named Lab 8.asm) the  function Average.The first parameter is the number of elements in an array, the second is the address of the array.The function will determine the average of the values in the  array  and  return  the  average  rounded  to  the  nearest  whole  number  (if  the fractional  part  of  the  result  is  equal  to  or greater  than  .5, the  result is  rounded  to the next higher number.

.cpp code

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std; 

extern "C" long Average(long, long[]);

int main()

{ 
long Array1[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }; 
long Array2[11] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 }; 
cout << "Average of Array1 is " << Average(10, Array1) << endl;
cout << "Average of Array2 is " << Average(11, Array2) << endl; 
}

long Average(long, long[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

.asm file

```
.386
.model flat

.data

public _Average
Average dw  10

.code



_Average    proc
            mov     ebx, [esp+8];
            mov     eax, [esp+4];
            xor     ecx, ecx;
            Loop1:
            add     ecx, 4;
            dec     ecx;
            jnz     Loop1;
            Done1:
            add     eax, 0;
            ret
_Average    endp




            end
```

Comment: why is that flagged with "PHP"?

Comment: Don't know about which particular assembly errors you are asking, but `fdiv eax` does not exist on x86. Nor you would want it to exist. `fdiv` is float point value division (either 32/64b IEEE-754 encoded number in memory, or 80b internal FP register of x87), while you have integer in `eax`. You can do `fidiv [integer_in_memory]` to divide 80b FP value on top of x87 fp-stack by integer in memory. But your task doesn't require you to work with floating point math, as all your values are integer-like (to get rounded result do `(S+trunc(N/2))/N` instead of `S/N` to get average. (22+2)/4=6 vs 22/4

Comment: And the rest of your assembly... is actually even worse... it makes very little sense, would you add to each part some description how did you come with such code, maybe it would be possible to see some sense in it and explain your mistakes, but as is, it's total non-sense and you can throw it away and try again. Google first for some summing array example for your target platform, make sure it works, then observe it in debugger HOW it works, use instruction reference guide to learn about each instruction... then only the division part will remain.

Comment: @Ped7g my professor is the one who came up with parts of the first few lines like mov ebx, [esp+8] and xor ecx,ecx. The rest was from my knowledge as well as what was in the textbook as I was looking around to see how to round a number to the nearest whole and the only thing I found was fdiv

Comment: @LarsStegelitz sorry I accidentally published the question when I was trying to write a different tag. LOL

Comment: I took out some of the other things like fdiv and now the only errors i'm getting are LNK2005 _Average already defined in Lab8.obj and LNK1169 one or more multiply defined symbols found.

Comment: `fdiv` does not round numbers to nearest. It sounds like you are reading through walls of text skimming it to few words, trying to guess which are relevant. Unfortunately for you assembly doesn't like that, unless you are unlucky with books choice, it's quite likely the whole wall of text was relevant, and it will take several re-reads, experiments with debugger, and study of additional materials, to figure out just the basics of it. Anyway, if you would put into source some comments, what was your intention to add particular instruction, it may give us hint how you think about the code.

Comment: Don't keep reposting the same question

Comment: You can edit your question to add exact errors, add platform, tools you use, options you use to compile, and make this wholesome [MCVE]. Meanwhile you may even try to improve the content of source itself, like explaining what you tried and why. I don't think that new one is duplicate, because this "question" at this state doesn't have any question in it... But so far you have only one "close" vote on this one, so you have still lot of opportunity to edit this one into better one: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask