# Assembly Definition Errors

Tags: function, assembly, symbols

I am trying to mess around with my assembly function to get it to work but have ran into a couple of errors that are difficult to get by. One is A2005 which states symbol redefinition :_Average.
The other one is A1010 which states unmatched block nesting :_Average
Any help is appreciated.

.cpp code

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std; 

extern "C" long Average(long, long[]);

int main()

{ 
long Array1[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }; 
long Array2[11] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 }; 
cout << "Average of Array1 is " << Average(10, Array1) << endl;
cout << "Average of Array2 is " << Average(11, Array2) << endl; 
}

long Average(long, long[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

.asm file

```
.386
.model flat

public _Average

.data

.code


_Average    proc
            push    ebp;
            mov     edx, 10;
            mov     ebx, [ebp+12]
            xor     ecx, ecx;
            xor     eax, eax;
        Loop1:
            add     eax, [edx + (ecx * 4)];
            inc     ecx;
            cmp     ecx, edx;
            jnz     Loop1;
        Done1:
            mov     ebx, 2;
            idiv            ebx;
            pop     ebp;
            ret
_Average    endp

_Average    proc
            push    ebp;
            mov     edx, 11;
            mov     ebx, [ebp+12];
            xor     ecx, ecx;
            xor     eax, eax;
        Loop2:
            add     eax, [edx + (ecx * 4)];
            inc     ecx;
            cmp     ecx, edx;
            jnz     Loop2;
        Done2:  
            mov     ebx, 2;
            idiv    ebx;
            pop     ebp;
            ret
_Average    endp


            end
```

Comment: Why do you have the code twice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assembly Language Errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49412315/assembly-language-errors)

Comment: He has actually three `_Average` functions in this source? The C one.. oh, it's probably C++ source, so the last in C++ will get name-mangled to somewhat different symbol, ok, so you have _Average defined probably just twice (as long as you don't compile that C++ source as C, then you have three of them).

Comment: @Ped7g: actually, the `extern "C"` prototype for `Average(long, long[])` disables name mangling, even though it's not used in the definition.  I checked with gcc: https://godbolt.org/g/6iyfAY, and it doesn't warn about omitting the `extern "C"` from the def, so presumably that's standard and MSVC would behave the same.  So yes, three definitions.  (Logan: The `extern "C"` prototype *without* a definition is required to call the asm `_Average` instead of `_Z8AveragelPl` or however MSVC would mangle the name.  Don't also define the function in C++).